# How can i verify if an user input is the same as a given string? Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, user-input

I need to count how many correct answers the user has after pressing a 'verify' button:

[image: i need to count how many correct answers the user has after pressing a 'verify' button]

The code for the form :

```
  <form>
<h5> Write the ing <i>ing</i> of the verbs.
  <ol>
    <li> live   → <input type="text" name="10" id="10"> </li>
    <li> stay  → <input type="text" name="11"> </li>
    <li> run    → <input type="text" name="12"> </li>
    <li> win    → <input type="text" name="13"> </li>
    <li> cyrcle → <input type="text" name="14"> </li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Use a `get` method to pass the values when pressing the form submit button and a `js` function which will compare the results by name.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as said in the comments, you should work on your questions.
You are looking for a way to get the value of an DOM Element using it's `name` attribute.
There is a function called `document.querySelector()` that takes a CSS selector as argument. The one you're looking for is `input[name="10"]` where `10` is the name.

With a loop you can iterate over all values from 10 to 14.

```
for (let i = 10; i < 15; i++){
       const user = document.querySelector(`input[name="${i}"]`).value;
}
```

Now compare it to the real values and then do whatever you want with it.

Here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2a4dpz59/18/

Answer (score 0):

To compare two strings in Javascript, you can write something like:

```
if (document.getElementById("id").value === "correct answer") {
  /* your code here */
}
```

Just make sure whether your `id` attribute is valid (ideally, it should start with a lowercase character).

If you want your comparison of strings to be independent of case, you can turn them both to lowercase, like this (or uppercase, doesn't matter):

```
if (document.getElementById("id").value.toLowerCase() === "correct answer".toLowerCase()) {
  /* your code here */
}
```

Comment: I think `str1 === str2` is easier to understand.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my answer, the second you commented that. I forgot this was not C :D

Comment: ty guys,it works now
it was my 1st question si it'll get better in the future